# How to Get Child Class Name of a Parent Interface in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I want to get the child class name which is implemented by an interface.
For example

```
public interface A
public class B implements A
public class C implements A
...
```

In my code I have declared the interface A and have set the value to one of these classes. So what I have is this:

```
A a = object.getA();
```

Now I want to get the current child class name, so B, C or whatever, but I don't want to do it with instanceof because I have many child classes which makes the code unnessesary long.
I am basically looking for this but getChild() doesn't exist of course.

```
a.getChild().getClass().getName()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like what you're looking for is:

```
String name = a.getClass().getName();
// Or
String simpleName = a.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

If the class of object «a» is an instance of B then getSimpleName() will return "B". It return "C" if «a» is an instance of C and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
interface A {
}
class B implements A {
}

class C implements A {
}
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```